# How do I map an integer to a row in an Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to create a discretized action space for a RL model with 5*5*5 = **125** actions. The model has 3 action variables which is represented as the index of a 1x3 array.

i.e:

```
[0][0][0] - 1
[0][0][1] - 2
[0][0][2] - 3
.
.
[4][4][3] - 124
[4][4][4] - 125
```

My initial thinking is to map an integer to a row of a numpy array as above. Is there a simple way to generate such numpy array and map to each row?

Comment: It is not very clear what is your input and output. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually simpler that it seems. Just create a range and reshape it:

```
arr = np.arange(1, 126).reshape((5, 5, 5))
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
array([[[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
        [  6,   7,   8,   9,  10],
        [ 11,  12,  13,  14,  15],
        [ 16,  17,  18,  19,  20],
        [ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25]],

       [[ 26,  27,  28,  29,  30],
        [ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35],
        [ 36,  37,  38,  39,  40],
        [ 41,  42,  43,  44,  45],
        [ 46,  47,  48,  49,  50]],

       [[ 51,  52,  53,  54,  55],
        [ 56,  57,  58,  59,  60],
        [ 61,  62,  63,  64,  65],
        [ 66,  67,  68,  69,  70],
        [ 71,  72,  73,  74,  75]],

       [[ 76,  77,  78,  79,  80],
        [ 81,  82,  83,  84,  85],
        [ 86,  87,  88,  89,  90],
        [ 91,  92,  93,  94,  95],
        [ 96,  97,  98,  99, 100]],

       [[101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
        [106, 107, 108, 109, 110],
        [111, 112, 113, 114, 115],
        [116, 117, 118, 119, 120],
        [121, 122, 123, 124, 125]]])

>>> arr[0][0][0]
1

>>> arr[0][0][1]
2

>>> arr[0][0][2]
3

>>> arr[4][4][3]
124

>>> arr[4][4][4]
125
```

Slightly more dynamic version:

```
factors = [5, 5, 5]
arr = np.arange(np.prod(factors)).reshape(factors)
```